# RhinoMocks Stub return real instance

Tags: unit-testing, constructor, rhino-mocks, stub

I'm trying to use RhinoMocks to stub out a third party component. The third party component looks like the following.

```
public class connection
{
    public connection(string host,int port)
    {}

    public void Submit(message msg)
    {}
}

public class message
{
    public message(string recipient)
    {}
{
```

When I attempt to use a stub it instead returns an actual instance of the object and my message will actually be sent if I use a valid host and port. If I don't use a valid host or port the constructor on the connection object throws an exception. I don't want a real object I just want a stub. What am I missing? Below is my code.

```
        Connection con = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Connection>("host", 25);
        Message msg = new Message("asdf@adsf.com");
        msg.AddRecipient(new Recipient("asdf@adsf.com"));
        con.Submit(msg);
```